# My code does not print as the example below

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
grid = []
 for row in range(4):
        grid.append([])
    for column in range(3):
        grid[row].append([0])
    for row in range(4):
        print('|', end =' ')
        for column in range(3):
            print(grid[row][column])
            if(column == 3):
                print('|')
```

it's not printing the box below as I expected

```
|         |
|         |
|         |
|         |
```

Comment: Is that your actual indentation?

Comment: Note that column == 3 is never True - range(3) provides the numbers *up to* 3 but not including 3. Your grid is also filled with 0 instead of spaces, so that cannot match your desired output either.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit messy. It looks like you want to create a grid of rows and columns and the content of your grid should look like the output you described.

I adjusted your code a little bit and added some explanations. See if this works for you.

```
#first, lets create the grid.
grid = []
for row in range(4):
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(3):
        if column in [0, 2]: #if it's the first or the last column, add a "|"
            grid[row].append('|')
        else: #if it's any other columnt, add a space " "
            grid[row].append(' ')

#now that we filled the grid, let's iterate over it and print each entry.
for row in grid: 
    for entry in row:
        print(entry,end=' ')
    print() #print a newline after each row
```

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to help.  I wanted to fill each cell in the grid (4x3) with, say 0.   So, I changed the line grid[row].append(' ') to grid[row][column].append(' ').  But I got an error: grid[row][column].append(0) IndexError: list index out of range.  The output I expected looks like the figure below:|         |
|         |
|         |
|         |
 ---------

Comment: it is important to see the difference between `append()`, which adds a new element to a list and the set operation `grid[row][col] = 0`. `grid[row][column]` is not a list, but it is an element in your grid, so you cannot `append(0)` to it and you get an error. Instead, you want to set the element to 0: `grid[row][col] = 0`

Comment: grid = []
for row in range(4):
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(3):
        if column in [0, 2]: #if it's the first or the last column, add a "|"
            grid[row].append('|')
        else: #if it's any other columnt, add a space " "
            grid[row][column] = 0  #this line resulted in an error: IndexError: list assignment index out of range.   Why so?  The logic seems OK to me.

Comment: And how do I display my code on this message board like you did.  This editor doesn't allow me to do so nicely.  The code mixed in the message.

Comment: You get the error because when you try to assign 0 to that position, the list is not yet big enough, there exists no position with the given index. that's why you need to use `append()` there, which will add an element to the list and also increase it's size by 1. You can use backquotes to display code here.

Comment: Here is my output: | |A| |A| |A| | 
| |A| |A| |A| | 
| |A| |A| |A| | 
| |A| |A| |A| | 
  ---   ---   ---  'The bottom row not lined up with the column above.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: Here is the code: 'grid = []
    for row in range(5):
        # Add an empty array that will hold each cell
        # in this row
        grid.append([])
        for column in range(5):
   
            if column in [0, 4]:
                grid[row].append('|')
                grid[row].append            
            else:
                grid[row].append('|A|')
    for column in range(5):
        if column in [0, 4]:
            grid[row][column] = ''
        else:
            grid[row][column] = ' ---

Answer (score -1):

you treat it complex it's simple solution here:

```
for i in range(4):
  print('|' + (' '*9 +'|'))
```

that works for you

Comment: not really what op asked for, but if you wanna do it as short as possible, might as well do this `print(('|'+(' '*9+'|\n'))*4)`

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestion.  What I wanted to build, as part of my homework, is a Game of Column, like Tetris.  But first, I need to build a empty field (grid) with row and column.  I am familiar with C/C++.  However, in Python, the indexing, looping, spacing caused quite a few confusion for me.  Essentially, I think List contents list (with cells) will help me to complete the project, but it's so hard to build a field with all the compiling issues.
|  [Z]   |
|         |
|         |
 ---------